# Angularjs highchart doesn't show in IE and SAFARI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, safari

highchart doesn't show in IE and SAFARI. I try the solution from the official highchart forum, but nothing help (remove "," at the end of json, or resize page on load etc...  )
I have multiple different highcharts, but here is only one for explanation. I call config function depends on chart data. My app have many different parts, and it's very hard to make working plunker. Thnx

Here is my code

```
function getBaseChartConfig(graphName) {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });
            var config =
                    {
                        xAxis: {
                            ordinal: false
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                        },
                        options: {
                            chart: {
                                zoomType: 'x',
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                                polar: true,
                                type: 'line',
                                borderRadius: 5

                            },
                            legend: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                            rangeSelector: {
                                //za postavit rucni upis date range-a
                                enabled: false,
                                inputStyle: {
                                    color: 'black'
                                }
                            },
                            navigator: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: [],
                        title: {
                            text: graphName
                        },
                        useHighStocks: true
                    };
            return config;
        };
$scope.data.push(solar_voltage);
            $scope.data.push(battery_voltage);
            $scope.data.push(solar_current);
            $scope.data.push(hybridCurrent);
            $scope.chartConfig1 = getChartConfigWithYaxisPlotLines('Production');
            $scope.chartConfig1.series.push({
                id: 1,
                name: "Solar voltage",
                data: $scope.data[0],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: "Battery voltage",
                data: $scope.data[1],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 3,
                name: "Solar current",
                data: $scope.data[2],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 4,
                name: "Hybrid current",
                data: $scope.data[3],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }
            );
 function getChartConfigWithYaxisPlotLines(graphName) {
            var baseChartConfig = getBaseChartConfig(graphName);
            baseChartConfig.yAxis.plotLines = [{
                    color: '#FF0000',
                    width: 1,
                    value: 11.50,
                    label: {text: '11.50'}
                }];
            return baseChartConfig;
        }
```

Here is image how this look in safari or IE 
[image]

And here is in CHROME and FIREFOX
[image]

This is my json from api
[image]

Comment: Can you paste $scope.data[0]? I think that your problem is incorrect x values (dates). Highstock uses timestamp in miliseconds but you have values like "2017-07-03 09:30:03". In Chrome it will be correctly parsed to the date, but in Safari it will throw an error (invalid date). The correct format is the same as for Date.parse() https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse. Sothe solution should be parse the strings to correct dates - timestamps.

Comment: Thnx @morganfree , i will try your solution tomorow when i be back in office.

Comment: @morganfree this is $scope.data[0]    0:1496822400000
1:3.7
length:2