# Date.parse() not working with highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I use HIGHCHART in angularjs app. 
I get from API date

```
var dateTime = new Date(value.date_time); // Wed Jun 07 2017 10:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

after I convert to unixTimeStamp

```
var unixTimeStamp1 = dateTime.getTime(); // 1496822400000
```

And this working normally in google chrome and firefox when opening highchart, but in Safari and IE not working. Now I need to convert to milliseconds

```
var unixTimeStamp = Date.parse(unixTimeStamp1); // here i get NaN
```

and all charts is empty.

If I try this instead of above

```
var unixTimeStamp = new Date(unixTimeStamp1*1000); // Wed May 24 49476 06:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

this work in all browser (IE, Safari, Chrome, Firefox...) but, date in the chart is not correct. 
With this, I get date like this on image bellow 
[image]

this is the correct date
[image]

My apologies if this is a duplicate question, but I didn't find the correct answer for my problem.

Comment: What is the value of `value.date_time`?

Comment: value.date_time = 2017-06-07 10:00:00

Comment: okay then you get only `time` then convert to date. You have a correct date. but why you need to change it a time then change to date?

Comment: You need to show only date part excluding time from date?

Comment: here I was ask for help, because highchart not rendering in safari and IE, and user there tell that problem is my date format. This is my topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887975/angularjs-highchart-doesnt-show-in-ie-and-safari?noredirect=1#comment76758832_44887975

Comment: I showing full date, but highchart depends on zoom show only date if zoom out, or if zoom in then highchart show date and time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Date.parse to parse that string and be sure that it works on every browser - see [the description of Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> Because of the variances in parsing of date strings, it is recommended to always manually parse strings as results are inconsistent, especially across different ECMAScript implementations where strings like "2015-10-12 12:00:00" may be parsed to as NaN, UTC or local timezone.

If your date has the format like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, you can parse it like this:

```
const date = '2017-06-07 10:00:00'
const d = date.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/)
const parsed = new Date(d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6]).getTime()
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/zt1k31sf/